# Coding a Terminal for ANdroid which communicates a Remote Server

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, android-service, terminal-emulator

I'm reformulating the question with some extra information, due it was on "on hold" state. I'll remove the other question.

I am trying to build an app which is a Console (like cmd), where I can send orders (commands) and I receive the response from a server.

So what I should see in my screen is my order and then server's response.

What should I do for this purpose?

I'm trying with a `Service`. But Service can't work with Network.

`AsyncTask` will finish when I send the first command. So I'll have to reconnect every time I decide to send an order (unefficient?)

`IntentService` is bounded to Activity's life. And finishes same way that `Asynctask` does.

*How can I do a Thread where, for the first time, it connects to the server. Then, every time I send to the thread a message, it contacts the server and retrieves my TextEdit the info from the server?*

---

**Edited for [on hold] state. Adding more info**

---

Here is what I have:

- An `Activity` with a `TextView` (used for terminal prompt), a `EditText` (allows user to put the command he wants to send) and a `Button` to send it.
- That `Activity` is bounded to a `Service` this way:

  ```
  ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

      public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
          mBounded = false;
          mServer = null;
      }

      public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
          mBounded = true;
          StatusService.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (StatusService.LocalBinder)service;
          mServer = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();


          /* once it is bounded, update data */
          updateSensorsData();


      }
  };

  /* ---------------- LIFE CYCLE METHODS -------------------------*/

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_console);

      Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, StatusService.class);
      bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

      /* Scrollable TextView for Console Prompt*/
      TextView tvConsole = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvConsole);
      tvConsole.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
  }
  ```
- The `Service` should interact with the Server and retrieve the info to the `TextView`, so I implemented:

  ```
  public String sendMessage(String message) {

      /* HERE I SHOULD CONNECT TO THE SERVER, BUT I DONT KNOW HOW */
      String response;

      connect(server, port);
      sendReceiveCmdControl(message);


      return response;
  }

  protected String sendReceiveCmdControl(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
      String res;


      send(controlOut, msg+"\n");
      // wait for response
      try {
          waitFor(controlIn, msg);
      } catch (EOFException e) {
          Log.d("ERROR", "Remote connection closed.");
          return "error";

      } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.d("ERROR", "IO problem.");
          return "error";
      } // end try
      // read the rest
      try {
          res = controlIn.readLine();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.d("ERROR", "IO problem.");
          return "error";
      } // end try


      return(res);
  } // end sendReceiveCmdControl()
  ```

Where controlOut is a `PrintWriter`, controlIn a `DataInputStream`, both initialized in method `connect` as follows:

```
   /* Connection I/O */
   public static Socket controlSocket = null;
   public static PrintWriter controlOut = null;
   public static DataInputStream controlIn = null;
   public static Socket imageSocket = null;
   public static PrintWriter imageOut = null;
   public static DataInputStream imageIn = null;

   protected void connect(String server, int port, boolean controlEnabled, boolean imageEnabled) {

        if (imageEnabled) {
            try {
                imageSocket = new Socket(server, port);
                imageOut = new PrintWriter(imageSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                imageIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(imageSocket.getInputStream()));
                Log.d("INFO", "Connected to image socket correctly");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                disconnect();
                Log.d("ERROR", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                disconnect();
                Log.d("ERROR", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }

        }

        if (controlEnabled) {
            try {
                controlSocket = new Socket(server, port+1);
                controlOut = new PrintWriter(controlSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                controlIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(controlSocket.getInputStream()));
                Log.d("INFO", "Connected to control socket correctly");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                disconnect();
                Log.d("ERROR", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                disconnect();
                Log.d("ERROR", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            } 

        }

    }
```

So what I want to do is:

1. Connect to the server with method `connect` the 1st time I run the Service.
2. Every time I want to send an order to the remote server, I should do `mServer.sendMessage(command);` in my Activity.
3. So the `Service` interacts with the Remote `Server`, and when it gets a response, the `Service` retrieves the response to the `Activity` for an UI update.

If there is another proper way than `Activity-Service-Thread/Whatever...` let me know please 
Thanks for any help. And thanks for your patience.

Comment: Um, a service can work with the network.  In fact its very common.  Why do you think it can't?

Comment: @GabeSechan it throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException` (I'll take a break, brb, I just came from office and I am completely tired)

Comment: That means you need to move it to an AsyncTask or Thread within the Service.  Services still run on the main (UI) thread but can create additional ones.

Comment: @GabeChan so how can I make a Thread and communicate with it from the Service? Can I make a Thread which is connected to the server always and waits for a message to send?

Comment: You create a Thread with new Thread(), then start it with start().  Yes, you can make the thread always connected to the server-  just have it open the connection and never close it.  If you need to send commands to the thread, use a message queue (easy way is to use a synchronized list) to add commands and have the thread check it for new commands.

Comment: @GabeSechan okay thanks. I'll give it a try. But, what about retrieving data from the Thread? Maybe should I use `runOnUiThread` to update the Activity?

Comment: Many many thanks dude. Now working properly. Btw, I deleted the Service and called the Thread directly. That step wasn't usefull at all.